# Bootstrap: fluid layout with no external margin

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap, margin, fluid-layout

if i have:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span8">
             Some Element....
       </div>
       <div class="span4">
             Other Element
       </div>   
   </div>       
</div>
```

With this code i have some margin from left and right window borders. How can eliminate these margins?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, I believe you want this:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Also if you are using responsive bootstrap you will also want this:

```
@media (max-width: 797px) {
    body { 
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
}
```

Edit: here is [a js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/w2d7r/1/).

Comment: In this case your content is going to stick to the window borders.

Comment: Bootstrap 4, which was released long after this useful answer, now has utility classes for this. You basically add `p-0` to the conainer.

I've posted an answer explaining the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54589229/199263

Answer (score 12):

The effect you are seeing is because of the `container`’s padding.

You can change the `container`’s default padding with the built-in [Bootstrap 4 spacing utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/).

To remove the padding, add `p-0` to the `container`:

```html
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
         Some Element....
       </div>
       <div class="col-4">
          Other Element
       </div>   
    </div>       
</div>
```

Using the built-in utility classes has the benefit of keeping your CSS lean and it also does not modify the default `container-fluid` class definition.

Comment: If you do this you'll end up with a horizontal scroll bar due to 15px of blank space to the right of the screen. You're ignoring the negative margins on the `row` class, which is why the padding is there on the container. You could fix by also adding the `m-0` class to every top-level row (it wouldn't be needed on any rows within rows).

Comment: @CraigBrown this comment greater than answers.
`<div class="container-fluid p-0">
<div class="row m-0">
<div class="row">`

Comment: p-0 do the trick. This is a best answer since you don't touch the .css but use bootstrap elements.