# How I can remove this bootstrap container-fluid default margin? Please see the attached image

Tags: html, css

When I wanted to add a navbar in the parent class .container-fluid. the navbar is taking a default left right margin as you can see the image here [Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1KOj.jpg)

here is my code-

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <nav id="navbar_top" class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
                <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Campaign</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400793/bootstrap-fluid-layout-with-no-external-margin This might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Bootstrap 5 the .no-gutters class has been replaced with .g-0. Use it
> on the .row where you want no spacing between columns.
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/21256143/244811

`.g-0` has been added to the `.col-lg-12` div,  which appears to have had the gutters:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="g-0 col-lg-12">
            <nav id="navbar_top" class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
                <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Campaign</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4. g-0 is not working